# Variant of the linear programming problem

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, convex-optimization, linear-programming, combinatorial-optimization

Good afternoon, my experience in mathematical programming is low. I would like to know if there is any general method to address the following problem:

$$\text{Minimize }\sum_{i=1}^n d_i(x_j)$$
$$s.a.\quad Ax=b,$$
$$~~~~~~~~\qquad x\geq 0,$$
where $A$ is a matrix $m\times n$ with rank $m$, $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$,  $b\in\mathbb{R}^m$, and 
\begin{equation*}
d_j(x_j) =
\begin{cases}
0, & \text{if $x_j= 0$},\\
d_jx_j+t_j, & \text{if $x_j> 0$},
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
$d_j,x_j$ are constants.

Very grateful for your answers and references of the problem mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

If $x_j \le u_j$ for some constant $u_j$, you can introduce a binary variable $y_j$, nonnegative variable $z_j$, and linear constraints:
\begin{align}
x_j &\le u_j y_j \\
d_j x_j + t_j - z_j &\le t_j(1-y_j)
\end{align}
The objective is then to minimize $\sum_{j=1}^n z_j$.

Comment: Thanks, could you give me some references?

Comment: These are called *big-M constraints*.  [Here](https://orinanobworld.blogspot.com/2018/09/choosing-big-m-values.html) is a good blog post about them.